# How can I animate a div to go to a specific spot on the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I think this problem is relatively simple, but I can't figure it out.

My goal is to smoothly animate the navbar to the top right of the page. 
However, the code as is does not animate it, it just reappears at the top.

Meanwhile, the name div does animate, but it seems to be popping weirdly out of place.

Is there an obvious solution that I'm not thinking about here?

Here's the CSS and codepen:

https://codepen.io/dane2476/pen/oJaoEJ

```
body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.name{
  padding:50px;
  font-size:40px;
  position: fixed;
  transition:1s;
}

.bar{
    margin-right:80%;
    margin-left:1%;
    border: 1.5px solid black;
 }
.bottom{
  background-color:black;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  width:100vw;
  height:50vh;
  transition:1s;
}
.nav{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    padding-bottom:100px;
    padding-right:100px;
    transition:1s;
}

.btn{
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-right:50px;
  background:none;
  color:white;
  font-size:25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  transition:1s;
}

/* Transition classes */

.name.animateName{
  top:25px;
  left:40px;
  padding:0;
  font-size:25px;
  transition:1s;
  position:fixed;
}
.nav.animateNav{
  top:25px;
  right:40px;
  position:fixed;
  transition:1s;
}
.btn.navButton{
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-right:50px;
    background:none;
    color:black;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    transition:1s;
}
.bottom.out{
  transform:translateY(100vh);
  transition:1s;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your **nav** class.
You are setting the bottom position for the **nav** then while animating it you're giving it a top position which is making your animation to not work.

Solution:

```
.nav{
position:fixed;
top: 80%; //or any value that works for you
right:0;
padding-bottom:100px;
padding-right:100px;
transition:1s;
```

}

This will make your animation work as you already have a top position given to the **nav** class.

Comment: Thanks! This is more concise than the first answer

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You are animating different property like `bottom` and when element added then `top` and you can't animation `top:auto` so you need to animate `bottom` or `top` with specific position or `%` and `name div` does animate but `nav` animate taking time so it display slow animate, check it

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(button){
    button.onclick = function (){
      document.querySelector('.name').classList.toggle('animateName');
      document.querySelector('.nav').classList.toggle('animateNav');
      document.querySelector('.bottom').classList.toggle('out');
      
      document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach(function(btn){
        btn.classList.toggle('navButton');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.name{
  padding:50px;
  font-size:40px;
  position: fixed;
  transition:1s;
}

.bar{
    margin-right:80%;
    margin-left:1%;
    border: 1.5px solid black;
 }
.bottom{
  background-color:black;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  width:100vw;
  height:50vh;
  transition:1s;
}
.nav{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:100px;
    right:100px;
    transition:all 1s;
    top:80%;
}

.btn{
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-right:50px;
  background:none;
  color:white;
  font-size:25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  transition:1s;
}

/* Transition classes */

.name.animateName{
  top:25px;
  left:40px;
  padding:0;
  font-size:25px;
  transition:1s;
}
.nav.animateNav{
  top:25px;
  right:40px;
  transition:all 1s;
  bottom:80%;
}
.btn.navButton{
    color:black;
    font-size:20px;
    transition:all 1s;
}
.bottom.out{
  transform:translateY(100vh);
  transition:1s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="name">
    My Name
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bottom">
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <button class="btn">This</button>
    <button class="btn">is</button>
    <button class="btn">a</button>
    <button class="btn">test</button>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Was already writing my own answer. In order for transition to work, the css property must be already defined before transitioning, otherwise it will pop out like in the codepen sample.

Comment: @AbanaClara Yes True